# Can you have three consecutive black nodes in red-black search tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees

Suppose I am making a red-black search tree, and in my right subtree, I have a black node, then a red node, and it has two black children, the black children further black childrens. As such a lemma has been made that red-black trees with $n$ internal nodes have height at most $2\log(n+1)$, would this proof still hold for such a black tree?

Comment: Have a close look at the definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, a red-black tree can have all black nodes. In that case the tree is completely balanced and has the required bound.